# Need to read data from text file within brackets in Python

Tags: python

My text file has line as below. This type of line is present many times in the file.

> [Nov 22 22:27:13] INFO  -[com.macys.seo.business.impl.LinkBusinessImpl]- Executing Search(WS) Gateway request : KeywordVO (     keyword = GUESS    score = 83965    normalizedKeyword = GUESS    productIds = []    categoryIds = []    hotListed = false    blackListed = false    globalHotList = false    url = /buy/GUESS     )

I want to extract only the following data into a file, like:

> keyword = Guess, Score = 83965, hotListed = false, globalHotList = false    url = /buy/GUESS

Here's what I have so far:

```
def get_sentences(filename):
    with open('d:\log.log') as file_contents:
        d1, d2 = '( ', ' )' # just example delimiters
        for line in file_contents:
            if d1 in line:
                results = []
            elif d2 in line:
                yield results
            else: results.append(line)
    print results
```

Please advise.

Comment: Does the solution have to be Python? Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: I need to use python only. My code snippet is def get_sentences(filename):
    with open('d:\log.log') as file_contents:
        d1, d2 = '(  ', '  )' # just example delimiters
        for line in file_contents:
            if d1 in line:
                results = []
            elif d2 in line:
                yield results
            else:
                results.append(line)
            print results

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) may help do the parsing in a single pass:

```
import re, pprint

with open('d:\log.log') as f:
   s = f.read()
results = re.findall(r'KeywordVO \((.*?)\)', s)
pprint.pprint(results)
```

The regex above uses `KeywordVO` to recognize which parentheses are relevant (I'm guessing that you didn't want to match the `(WS)` part of the example text).  You will likely have to take a close look at your log file determine the exact regex that extracts the data you want.

Once you have the long text string for all the keyword pairs, use another regex to split-up the key/value pairs:  `r'[A-Za-z]+\s*=\s*[A-Za-z\[\]\,]'`.  This regex is tricky because you want to capture complex values on the right hand side of the equal sign but don't want to accidentally capture the next key (it is unfortunate that the key/value pairs aren't separated by a comma or somesuch.

Good luck with your parsing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+ = \S+', the_text)
['keyword = GUESS', 'score = 83965', 'normalizedKeyword = GUESS',
 'productIds = []', 'categoryIds = []', 'hotListed = false',
 'blackListed = false', 'globalHotList = false', 'url = /buy/GUESS']
```

Then you can split the `=` and grab the ones you need.

Something like that:

```
>>> data = re.findall(r'\w+ = \S+', the_text)
>>> ok = ('keyword', 'score', 'hotListed', 'url')
>>> [i for i in [i.split(' = ') for i in data] if i[0] in ok
[['keyword', 'GUESS'], ['score', '83965'], ['hotListed', 'false'], ['url', '/buy/GUESS']]
```

Comment: I am stuck in using split regex to grab the desired ones, please help

Comment: import re, pprint
with open('d:\log.log') as f:
   s = f.read()
results = re.findall(r'\w+ = \S+', s') This prints all Key/values pairs and I need only that defined in ok
ok = ('keyword', 'score', 'hotListed', 'url')
[i for i in [i.split(' = ') for i in results] if i[0] in ok]
pprint.pprint(results)