# Converting RGB data into an array from a text file to create an Image

Tags: arrays, image, numpy

I am trying to convert txt RGB data from *file.txt* into an array.  And then, using that array, convert the RGB array into an image. 
(RGB data is found at this github repository: [IR Sensor File.txt](https://github.com/abood91/RPiMLX90640/blob/master/file.txt)).

I am trying to convert the .txt file into an array which I could use the PIL/Image library and convert the array into an Image, and then put it through the following script to create my image.

My roadblock right now is converting the arrays in file.txt into an appropriate format to work with the Image function.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = [ARRAY FROM THE file.txt]
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

The RGB data looks like as follows, and can also be found at the .txt file from that github repository linked above:

```
[[(0,255,20),(0,255,50),(0,255,10),(0,255,5),(0,255,10),(0,255,25),(0,255,40),(0,255,71),(0,255,137),(0,255,178),(0,255,147),(0,255,158),(0,255,142),(0,255,163),(0,255,112),(0,255,132),(0,255,137),(0,255,153),(0,255,101),(0,255,122),(0,255,122),(0,255,147),(0,255,66),(0,255,66),(0,255,30),(0,255,61),(0,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,255,40),(0,255,66),(15,255,0),(0,255,15)],
[(0,255,40),(0,255,45),(15,255,0),(20,255,0),(10,255,0),(35,255,0),(0,255,5),(0,255,56),(0,255,173),(0,255,168),(0,255,153),(0,255,137),(0,255,158),(0,255,147),(0,255,127),(0,255,117),(0,255,142),(0,255,142),(0,255,122),(0,255,122),(0,255,137),(0,255,137),(0,255,101),(0,255,66),(0,255,71),(0,255,61),(0,255,25),(0,255,25),(0,255,61),(0,255,35),(0,255,0),(35,255,0)],
[(0,255,15),(0,255,25),(51,255,0),(71,255,0),(132,255,0),(101,255,0),(35,255,0),(0,255,20),(0,255,91),(0,255,153),(0,255,132),(0,255,147),(0,255,132),(0,255,158),(0,255,122),(0,255,132),(0,255,142),(0,255,158),(0,255,122),(0,255,137),(0,255,142),(0,255,147),(0,255,101),(0,255,101),(0,255,86),(0,255,86),(0,255,50),(0,255,45),(0,255,50),(0,255,56),(0,255,30),(56,255,0)],
[(0,255,45),(0,255,10),(76,255,0),(127,255,0),(132,255,0)]]
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the `Image` object, it seems fairly clear what you should hand it. What have you written so far to rewrite your data so that it "should" work with `Image.fromarray` but doesn't? You're using `mode='RGB'` so you're promising the `fromarray` function that you'll be giving it a byte array where each three bytes represent an {R,G,B} sequence. That seems pretty easy to generate off of the data you show, which already encodes R, G, and B values separately?

Comment: I tried 'np.loadtxt("file.txt")', but it threw me an error saying that it couldn't convert a string to a float.

Comment: Obviously. That's not trying to make it work, that's just blatantly ignoring the documentation of how `fromarray` even works =) The `fromarray` function expects an array of bytes, and by using `mode='RGB'` you are promising it an array of bytes where the first byte is the first pixel's value for R, the second the first pixel's value for G, the third the first pixel's value for B, then the fourth the second pixel's R, then G, then B, then the third pixel's R, G, B, etc. So first turn that list-inside-a-list of tuples into just a flat list of r, then g, then b values.

Comment: That makes sense.  How do I turn the list-within-list of tuples into a flat list?  I can select your answer, if you create a solution.

Comment: I'll be honest: that's something you should be able to find out entirely on your own, as that's just basic python around "how do I iterate over a list". Millions of great examples of how to do that on google, and stackoverflow, already

Comment: I am still having trouble with the error converting string to float.  Maybe someone can support?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much Python, but this looks like it could extract the numbers from your file https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283694/2836621 I guess the regular expression is `\d+` for one or more digits.

Comment: you convert strings that are _obviously_ numbers with `int(...)`, so `int("255")` becomes the number 255. But that's really super basic Python that any tutorial page should (.... "should"....) cover.

Comment: (as for loading your actual data so that it becomes a python variable: have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work - no idea if it's decent Python:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import re

# Read in entire file
with open('sensordata.txt') as f:
   s = f.read()

# Find anything that looks like numbers
l=re.findall(r'\d+',s)

# Convert to numpy array and reshape
data = np.array(l).reshape((24,32,3))

# Convert to image and save
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('result.png')
```

[image]

I enlarged and contrast-stretched the image subsequently so you can see it!